# Getting power consumption for each process

Tags: c#, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Battery Usage By Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737773/get-battery-usage-by-process)

Is there any way to find how much power is consumed by each processes and displaying in a list using c#?

Comment: What do you mean by power? CPU slice?

Comment: @Bridge That raises an interesting point: If they were to calculate the consumption of the program as a percentage of the total system consumption, they'd need to consider various power profiles...

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather difficult task to do, there is generally no standard hardware support for it in a normal computer.

If you are just after finding out how much power your PC is consuming I suggest using a wall plug power monitor: [http://www.amazon.com/P3-International-P4400-Electricity-Monitor/dp/B00009MDBU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00009MDBU)

Another tip could be that if you are using a UPS, you can sometimes get the power consumption using a vendor specific API.

Here is also a thread on msdn discussing how to get the general power consumption through C#, even this is difficult and there are no clear answers given. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharplanguage/thread/1eb2fc16-ceca-4984-acf8-cf81185d528f

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered various models but I'm not sure what *you* mean by power.

Which of the following do you want to consider?

- CPU
- Memory
- Disk IO

For charging processes on mainframes for example, they use pure CPU power (MIPS)

For charging on large databases, a function of CPU & disk IO is used (derived from the execution plan)