# Programmatically get process power usage in Windows 10 like Task Manager does

Tags: winapi

There are a few existing threads with that question. However, most of them were answered before Windows 10 Task Manager got power usage feature. Is there any information on how does it estimate it?

I am interested in scripting app restrictions based on their power usage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting power consumption for each process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949778/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau the question you linked is very old, answers there are probably outdated.

Comment: @LOST There seems no such API out of box for query process power usage. You may use performance counter like processor time, IO operations etc to estimate process power usage.